# Is there a call for If (inputtext.equals(string.name)) i would like to access my string.xml items name

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have a couple of text in my string names separately and would like to find if matches with input to the strings name id. I have put them in array and randomly taking one if the randomized matches with the input.

```
<string name="a">あ</string>
<string name="i">い</string>
<string name="u">う</string>
<string name="e">え</string>
<string name="o">お</string>
<string name="ka">か</string>
<string name="ki">き</string>
<string name="ku">く</string>
<string name="ke">け</string>
<string name="ko">こ</string>

<string-array name="kana">
    <item>@string/a</item>
    <item>@string/i</item>
    <item>@string/u</item>
    <item>@string/e</item>
    <item>@string/o</item>
    <item>@string/ka</item>
    <item>@string/ki</item>
    <item>@string/ku</item>
    <item>@string/ke</item>
    <item>@string/ko</item>
</string-array>
```

Is there such call for that?

```
if (answer.equals(kanaArray[generatedIndex])) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Sugoi!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "wrong!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
```

this showing what is the actual text in the string

[Screen Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5gtHJ.png)

Thank you

Edit:

Sorry. the user is to input like ka, a, ki and that input is to be matched with the string id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, now I KNOW you are using an `EditText` for user input instead of my assumption with buttons.  I don't think there's a good way to get the name strings of your hiragana strings.  However, you can effectively do the same thing by eliminating the kana array and using the string names of your hiragana strings directly with `getIdentifier`.  This is what I mean:

```
//I'm making assumptions still, but here I'm somehow getting to the kana
TextView flashcard = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.flashcard);
String kana_char = flashcard.getText();
```

Here the application package class is, for example,  `"com.example.kanaflashcards"` or whatever your project is named, and so `resolved_kana` becomes the kana of which ever romanji was entered, or empty string if what was entered was not a valid romanji string.  You can then match that against the `kana_char` you displayed.

```
String user_input = "<value from edit text>";
String resolved_kana = (String) getResources().getText(getResources().getIdentifier(user_input, "string", "<application package class>"),"");
if (resolved_kana.equals(kana_char) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Sugoi!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
} else {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "wrong!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: the Hiragana's is to appear and user has to input in a editText "ka" and if that matches the text kana appeared with its ID.

Comment: Ok, so I assumed a button with pre-determined string as opposed to an EditText, but its the same idea.  You take the editext string entered, and see if you can find a resource value matching it.  if it matches the kana your good.  You just need to add a default value to the `gettext()` call, say empty string, so that it won't match your resource names.  I'll make edits to the answer.

Comment: Ok I'm so dumb, ID is a number. ugh, i was trying as if able to get the "name" of the kanas. the user has to input the "ki" and has to match with the name of the string name. Im so sorry for missinterpert. And the question was to get the <string name="ki">き</string> the "name". If (ka"userinput" = ka"of string name") .....

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

```
String[] kanaArray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.kana);
for(int index=0; i<kanaArray.length; i++) {
    if (answer.equals(kanaArray[index])) { 
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Sugoi!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else { 
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "wrong!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```